Pandas: Prevent (blank) from being read as ''
I'm loading a dataframe that has a column with string (blank) in it. I want to read this as is, i.e as a string itself, and to be displayed in the output, instead of being converted to any other form (Nan, <NA>, '' etc.).
This is not a duplicate question. I tried several stack overflow suggestions. The closest that answered mine were this question and this one (keep_default_na=False and na_values=['']), although it still converts cells with string (blank) to nan.
Is there any way I can get (blank) itself as a string. As it's required to not create confusion for the end user.
By the way, I also tried converting using dtype as well, but to no avail. It still converts to <NA>.

you have 3 parameters, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter to use depending on whether you want to avoid all conversion to NaN or just ''. For just '', use keep_default_na=False,  na_values=['#N/A', '#N/A N/A', '#NA', '-1.#IND', '-1.#QNAN', '-NaN', '-nan', '1.#IND', '1.#QNAN', '<NA>', 'N/A', 'NA', 'NULL', 'NaN', 'None', 'n/a', 'nan', 'null']

I tried this. It doesn't work. Not sure why my question closed as duplicate. I have rephrased it in case i wasn't clear enough. What i'm looking is for is to prevent the string "(blank)" from being converted.

Can you provide a [mre] of CSV and the exact matching expected output?
